# two threads, first adds second substracts

Tags: c, pthreads

This is a classic example of mutex locks. I don't know why the following code doesn't work, ie. it doesn't print "ctr = 0" every time (but, for example, ctr = 535).

```
int ctr;
pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void * add (void * arg_wsk)
{
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                pthread_mutex_lock (&m);
                ctr++;
                pthread_mutex_unlock (&m);
        }
        return(NULL);
}

void * sub(void * arg_wsk)
{
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                pthread_mutex_lock (&m);
                ctr--;
                pthread_mutex_unlock (&m);
        }
        return(NULL);
}
int main()
{       
        pthread_t tid1, tid2;
        int i;
        void *res;
        ctr = 0;
        pthread_mutex_init(&m, NULL);

        pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, add, NULL);
        pthread_detach(tid1);

        pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, sub, NULL);
        pthread_detach(tid2);

        pthread_join(tid1, &res);
        pthread_join(tid2, &res);

        pthread_mutex_destroy(&m);
        printf("ctr = %d", ctr);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Failure to check any pthread library return values means you may be ignoring an important error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are misusing the POSIX API. If you detach the threads, you shouldn't join them. Remove the detach and see if this improves things. I think you'll see that main() now blocks until the threads have completed.

Note also, from the link for the join call

```
ESRCH  No  thread could be found corresponding to that specified by the
          given thread ID.
```

If you're lucky, you'll hit this. If you're not lucky, crazy things will happen. Don't mix detach and join calls on the same thread.

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Joining

Comment: Yup that fixed it for me.

Comment: That solves it, and you should also explore how to pass args to the threads. If you make ctr a local variable in `main()`, and change the call to `pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, add, &ctr)` I would view it as more readable code.

Comment: I wrongly assumed what "detached" means. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The value of your counter `ctr` depends on both the threads completing their full execution.

According to `pthread_detach(3)`

> Once a thread has been detached, it can't be joined with
>   pthread_join(3) or be made joinable again.

If you remove `pthread_detach` call from your program, you will get the expected output.

Also, consider explicitly creating your thread joinable(or detached) for portability.

Comment: You're right, but there are other ways the problem could be solved besides "don't detach the threads". This is really nothing more than another point of thread synchronization, where pthread_join (if possible; not possible in this case as you point out) is one form of synchronization.